# How to properly override get_queryset in a modelviewset without breaking the query by pk?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a ModelViewSet:

```
class OrderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
serializer_class = OrderSerializer
pagination_class = DefaultPagination
queryset = Order.objects.all()

def get_queryset(self):
    userId = self.request.query_params.get('userId')
    if userId is not None:
        query = Order.objects.filter(owner__id=userId).order_by('-createdAt')
    else:
        query = Order.objects.order_by('-createdAt')
    return query
```

Here is the url registration

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('api/v1/order', OrderViewSet, basename='order')
```

I found that after overriding the get_queryset, I can no longer query by one order id like the following anymore: `/api/v1/order/1`,it just returns `detail: not found`

I do see django saying it supports:

```
^api/v1/order/$ [name='order-list']
^api/v1/order\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='order-list']
^api/v1/order/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='order-detail']
^api/v1/order/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='order-detail']
```

what should be the correct way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this, call `super()` when overriding the `get_queryset()`

Give this a try

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(OrderViewSet, self).get_queryset()

    userId = self.request.query_params.get('userId')
    if userId is not None:
         queryset = queryset.filter(owner__id=userId).order_by('-createdAt')
    else:
        queryset = queryset.order_by('-createdAt')
    return queryset
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Thanks Sumithran! Another trick is in my code I wasn't returning a queryset but a dict, so that is another problem.

Comment: shouldn't you would be returning `queryset ` instead of `query`?

Comment: @RajuSingh nice catch, that was a typo, Fixed it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What about using Django's function-based views and class-based to your advantage. I can think of a solution where you can create another function based view to handle the above functionality and let the class based view get method handle the pk query set.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).